# Detect the specific script that causes DB blocked sessions

Tags: database

Folks,
I need guidance. Before scripts execution in a Database (Let it be Oracle/Postgre scripts). Is there any way to detect the specific script that causes DB blocked sessions during script execution starts?

Answer (score 0):

No, it is not possible to pre-identify whether that script would cause any locking in the database. But you can understand explain plan of the query before executing it.